# Subqueries to JOIN while keeping logic

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to optimize a slow query and I've come across the following (running consistently over 8 seconds).

```
SELECT entryID, entryID AS iE, 0 AS eE, 'clarus1' AS locationID, dateStamp, amount AS income, NULL AS expense, reconciled, leaseID AS vendorID, incomeID AS expenseID
FROM structu_income.iLedger 
WHERE (dateStamp BETWEEN '2009-04-16' AND '2012-02-29') AND incomeID IS NOT NULL
    AND (
        leaseID IN (
            SELECT lease.leaseID FROM structu_assets.lease WHERE lease.unitID IN (
                SELECT unit.unitID FROM structu_assets.unit WHERE unit.locationID = 'clarus1'
            )
        )
        OR locationID IN (SELECT locationID FROM structu_assets.deed WHERE ownerID = 'clarus')
    )
```

Here's the `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

My thought was to refactor the subqueries to use `JOIN`. But keeping the logical `OR` is throwing me off.

In addition, the nested subqueries seem inevitable. Unless I predetermined the `unitID` in a separate query.

I'm not the original developer. But I'm charged with making it more performant without modifying the existing codebase or schema. So I'm attempting the pick off the slow queries.

As an aside, do cross database queries take a performance hit?

Comment: There could be a hit if you're using primarily the HEAP (in-memory) engine, and then query a table that's using a disk-based system (e.g. myisam/innodb), but other than engine efficiency differences and a few extra permissions/security checks, there shouldn't be any noticeable hit.

Comment: @Marc B, All tables involved are MyISAM. Was your point in reference to my *aside* or the question in general.

Answer (score 1):

add an index to your dateStamp column.

use :

```
dateStamp > '2009-04-16' AND dateStamp < '2012-02-29'
```

instead of :

```
dateStamp BETWEEN '2009-04-16' AND '2012-02-29'
```

it's more efficient.

Finally, you can write a loop in PHP instead of subqueries.

Comment: There already is one. I found it interesting that it was not using it. IN addition, you're examples are not logically equivalent (midnight).

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to see if this answer **a)** works and **b)** is faster. Try this:

```
SELECT
    il.entryID,
    il.entryID AS iE,
    0 AS eE,
    'clarus1' AS locationID,
    il.dateStamp,
    il.amount AS income,
    NULL AS expense,
    il.reconciled,
    il.leaseID AS vendorID,
    il.incomeID AS expenseID
FROM
    structu_income.iLedger il
    INNER JOIN structu_assets.lease l ON il.leaseID = l.leaseID
    INNER JOIN structu_assets.unit u ON l.unitID = u.unitID AND u.locationID = 'clarus1'
WHERE
    il.dateStamp BETWEEN '2009-04-16' AND '2012-02-29'
    AND il.incomeID IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT
    il.entryID,
    il.entryID AS iE,
    0 AS eE,
    'clarus1' AS locationID,
    il.dateStamp,
    il.amount AS income,
    NULL AS expense,
    il.reconciled,
    il.leaseID AS vendorID,
    il.incomeID AS expenseID
FROM
    structu_income.iLedger il
    INNER JOIN structu_assets.deed d ON il.locationID = d.locationID AND d.ownerID = 'clarus'
WHERE
    il.dateStamp BETWEEN '2009-04-16' AND '2012-02-29'
    AND il.incomeID IS NOT NULL
```

The first `SELECT` query takes care of the first half of your `OR` conditions, and the second `SELECT` query adds in the results for the second half. And you shouldn't get duplicate rows with `UNION` so I believe you should get the same results.

Comment: Works. But no decrease in time when benchmarked. +1 for the thorough answer though.

Comment: You should at least be able to get rid of the sub-subquery (first part of your `OR` conditions) with a join. `SELECT lease.leaseID FROM structu_assets.lease INNER JOIN structu_assets.unit ON lease.unitID = unit.unitID WHERE unit.locationID = 'clarus1'`.